# How to open facebook and twitter links inside the iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

In my iphone app, there is a requirement where the user needs to open the facebook and twitter links right inside the app.

I tried using the UIApplication method to open the URL but then it leaves the app and opens safari.

I want that the links should open inside the app itself.

What should i do?

What is the better solution?

Please Help and Suggest

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an instance of `UIWebView` and pass your URL into that.